# Как сделать чтобы по клику на поле таблицы оно копировалось?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть таблица в которую подтягиваются данные клиента, и нужно чтобы по клику на эти данные они копировались, не представлю как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  const area = document.createElement('textarea');
  document.body.appendChild(area);  
  area.value = text;
  area.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(area);  
}
```